# What is the precision of the Fuel Quantity Indication System (FQIS) of the Boeing 777?

Tags: aircraft-performance, fuel-systems, boeing-777

What is the precision of the Boeing 777-300ER ultrasonic FQIS? If for example it is 2% when 100 tonnes of fuel are loaded, there could be anything between 98 tonnes and 102 tonnes. How is this accounted for in the MTOW calculation?

Comment: This is an interesting question. However I think the quantity of fuel loaded comes from the fuelling system (truck or underground delivery). Then again, they of course have their own tolerances...

Comment: @Jpe61 I don't think so. AFAIK you set a target fuel on the refueling panel of the aircraft and it automatically controls fuel flow and distribution until reaching that target. It will obviously use the onboard FQIS to measure fuel amounts. Even if a predetermined amount of fuel is added, you would calculate that amount based on fuel remaining in the tanks, so again using the FQIS.

Comment: Roger that @Bianfable! Do you crosscheck the fuel ordered/delivered with what the previous flight left and FQIS?